# Convert a string into a dataframe in Python

Tags: python, pandas, string, dataframe, numpy

I have a string which looks like this.

```
x = 24.55 26.22, 69.22 78.25, 66.25 45.98
```

I want to convert into a dataframe which looks like this:

```
  A       B      A     B      A      B
24.55   26.22  69.22  78.25  66.25  45.98
```

This is what I have tried, but I am getting an error.

```
import io
import pandas as pd
df1 = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(x), sep=",")
df1 =  df1.groupby(level=[0,1]).cumcount().map({0 : 'x', 1 : 'y'})
```

Comment: What error do you get? What is the exact error message? Can you [add](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/73335978/edit) it to your question? (But ******** ***without*** ******** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the question should appear as if it was written today)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a double split, `stack` and reshape to DataFrame:

```
x = '24.55 26.22, 69.22 78.25, 66.25 45.98'

out = (pd
       .DataFrame([map(float, s.split()) for s in x.split(',')],
                  columns=['A', 'B'])
       .stack().droplevel(0)
       .to_frame().T
      )
```

output:

```
       A      B      A      B      A      B
0  24.55  26.22  69.22  78.25  66.25  45.98
```

If you already know the number of items:

```
pd.DataFrame([[float(e) for s in x.split(',') for e in s.split()]],
             columns=['A', 'B']*3)
```